# Why forms do not hold their values in a multi-steps form created using provider in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, forms, provider, state-management, consumer

I have the following code that tries to create a multi steps forms :

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class UserModal extends ChangeNotifier {
  String? name;
  String? email;
  String? password;
  String? education;

  int activeIndex = 0;
  int totalIndex = 2;

  changeStep(int index) {
    activeIndex = index;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}



import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:form_field_validator/form_field_validator.dart';
import 'package:im_stepper/stepper.dart';
import 'package:multi_step_form/modal/user_modal.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class MultiPageProvider extends StatefulWidget {
  const MultiPageProvider({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MultiPageProviderState createState() => _MultiPageProviderState();
}

class _MultiPageProviderState extends State<MultiPageProvider> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<UserModal>(
      create: (context) => UserModal(),
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text(
            "Using Provider",
          ),
        ),
        body: Consumer<UserModal>(
          builder: (context, modal, child) {
            switch (modal.activeIndex) {
              case 0:
                return const BasicDetails();
              case 1:
                return const EducationDetails();

              default:
                return const BasicDetails();
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BasicDetails extends StatefulWidget {
  const BasicDetails({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _BasicDetailsState createState() => _BasicDetailsState();
}

class _BasicDetailsState extends State<BasicDetails> {
  GlobalKey<FormState> basicFormKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<UserModal>(builder: (context, modal, child) {
      return Form(
        key: basicFormKey,
        child: ListView(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(
            12.0,
          ),
          children: [
            Center(
              child: DotStepper(
                activeStep: modal.activeIndex,
                dotRadius: 20.0,
                shape: Shape.pipe,
                spacing: 10.0,
              ),
            ),
            Text(
              "Step ${modal.activeIndex + 1} of ${modal.totalIndex}",
              style: const TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20.0,
              ),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
            TextFormField(
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                labelText: "Name",
              ),
              validator: RequiredValidator(
                errorText: "Required *",
              ),
            ),
            TextFormField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  labelText: "Email",
                ),
                validator: MultiValidator([
                  RequiredValidator(
                    errorText: "Required *",
                  ),
                  EmailValidator(
                    errorText: "Not Valid Email",
                  ),
                ])),
            TextFormField(
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                labelText: "Passoword",
              ),
              validator: MinLengthValidator(
                6,
                errorText: "Min 6 characters required",
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 12.0,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 40.0,
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  if (basicFormKey.currentState?.validate() ?? false) {
                    // next
                    modal.changeStep(1);
                  }
                },
                child: const Text(
                  "Next",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    });
  }
}

class EducationDetails extends StatelessWidget {
  const EducationDetails({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<UserModal>(builder: (context, modal, child) {
      return ListView(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(
          12.0,
        ),
        children: [
          Center(
            child: DotStepper(
              activeStep: modal.activeIndex,
              dotRadius: 20.0,
              shape: Shape.pipe,
              spacing: 10.0,
            ),
          ),
          Text(
            "Step ${modal.activeIndex + 1} of ${modal.totalIndex}",
            style: const TextStyle(
              fontSize: 20.0,
            ),
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
          TextFormField(
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              labelText: "Name",
            ),
            validator: RequiredValidator(
              errorText: "Required *",
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 12.0,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 40.0,
            child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: const Text(
                "Register",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      );
    });
  }
}
```

But it can not hold the form values after I click on `Next` or `Back` buttons and can not hold the form values. I don't know what is the problem and howcan I fix it?
It seems maybe I should give a key value to provides inside the consumer but I don't know how?

Answer (score 1):

I first time misunderstood your question. Your problem is that you are changing the widgets in the consumer. To solve this problem, you need to either use a GlobalKeys for each case in the consumer, for example:

```
      switch (modal.activeIndex) {
          case 0:
            return const BasicDetails(key: _basicKey);
          case 1:
            return const EducationDetails(key: _educationKey);

          default:
            return const BasicDetails(key: _basicKey);
        }
```

, or store data outside of these widgets(you can use BLoC for example) and initialize them in build methods

Comment: How can I access the keys while they are defined on their own files/classes?

Comment: I also updated the question's codes. Please have a look.

Comment: You are not using the keys correctly, the point is that the global keys live longer than your widget, then they will save it, as if you hid it, and then showed it, so they should be stored higher in the tree, as I showed, access to them to you not needed

Answer (score 0):

I think this is due to the ListView optimization you can either go the wrong way: use shrinkWrap: true on ListView, or the right way: use TextEditingController or initialValue and onChange on TextFormField

Comment: shrinkWrap = true disables ListView optimization and all children always draws